# Creating a reusable Redux Wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-rails

I am working on a RoR project that uses webpacker and react-rails.  We are slowly moving away from haml to React.  Because of this, each page we are doing `react_component('page_to_render')` We are also using Redux and I had been calling my component directly in the Provider and it was working fine.  Because of the way we are using this, each page will in a sense be it's own React app, I am trying to make a reusable component to pass the store.  My thought was the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import store from './store'

class ReduxState extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
export default ReduxState
```

So for each page, we'd just have to wrap it in `<ReduxState></ReduxState>`, but when I do this I get:

`Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(BillingPage)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(BillingPage) in connect options.`

It seems that store should be passed down to anything wrapped in  but that isn't the case.  I feel like I might be missing something about how Redux works.  Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case. I'd expect that ReduxState and connected components use different copies of `react-redux` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more into my errors, I realized that I am returning the Provider within JSX and that the `BillingPage` class itself has no reference to `ReduxState`

I realized I needed a HOC.  Solution below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import store from './store'

const ReduxState = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default ReduxState
```

```
const composedHoc = compose(
  ReduxState,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
      addBill,
      removeBill
    }
  )
)

export default composedHoc(BillingPage)
```